# Concise way to include a file in a war with a different name

Tags: java, build, gradle, war

Right now, to include a developer dependent file in a war, I copy it in a temp directory, rename it and then include it in the war :

```
war {
    copy {
        from "run_"+System.getProperty('user.name')+".properties"
        into "build/tmp"
        rename ("run_"+System.getProperty('user.name')+".properties", "run.properties")
    }
    webInf {
        from('build/tmp') {
            include "run.properties"
        }
    }
}
```

It works but it's very verbose. I could define a variable for the file name but that wouldn't really be more concise.

I'm sure there's a concise syntax to do it, probably without creating any temporary file.

What is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
war {
    webInf {
       from("run_${System.getProperty('user.name')}.properties") {
          rename {
             'run.properties'
          }
       }
    }
}
```